# Autofac: register generic type with nongeneric interface

Tags: c#, generics, interface, autofac

I'm trying to register (as Instance per Request) the generic type and non-generic interface.
On internet I have found a lot of opposite examples, but none for this.

Thus, I have a class like this:

```
public class UnitOfWork<TContext> : IUnitOfWork where TContext : DbContext, new()
```

The generic class, but non-generic interface.
In Autofac I was trying to register that this way:

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(UnitOfWork<>)).As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

But I'm getting error:
*The service 'Namespace.UoW.IUnitOfWork' is not an open generic type definition.*

Of  course, because it is not. But I don't know how to register it.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have multiple DbContext in your solution? If a class uses an `IUnitOfWork` which `UnitOfWork<TContext>` should be used there?

Comment: `UnitOfWork<>` is a generic type declaration, but autofac needs to return concrete instance of concrete class. So, if you register it just as `IUnitOfWork` which concrete type parameter should Autofac use?

Comment: I have only one DbContext. So I should register it as this: builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(UnitOfWork<Context>)).As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerHttpRequest(); Right?
In that case I get error,  that UnitOfWork<Contex> is not an open generic type definition..

Comment: You don't need the `RegisterGeneric` you can just use the `RegisterType` `builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork<Context>>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstanceP‌​erHttpRequest(); `

Comment: Oh, such a simple. It is working, thank you.

Comment: @nemesv: You should promote your comment to answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You only need `RegisterGeneric` if you also have a generic interface.

In your case you only have a non generic interface `IUnitOfWork` and also only one `DbContext` derived class so you can just register your `UnitOfWork<Context>` as a normal type with:

```
builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork<Context>>()
       .As<IUnitOfWork>().InstanceP‌​erHttp‌​Request();
```

So any of your types requesting an `IUnitOfWork` will get an `UnitOfWork<Context>`.

Comment: But if I want to get another class? For exmaple:
public class MySecondContex : DbContext

Comment: If you don't have a generic itnerface e.g `IUnitOfWork<T>` You can just register the second one as the first one `builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork<MySecondContex>>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstanceP‌​erHttp‌​Request();` however if you want to resolve them seperatetly you need to regiter it with `Named` or `Keyed` see this in the doc: http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html